# using microtime() in password hash

Tags: php, hash

i saw an example of password hashing using microtime() as this

```
 public function create_hash($value)
{
    return $hash = crypt($value, '$2a$12$'.substr(str_replace('+', '.', base64_encode(sha1(microtime(true), true))), 0, 22));
}
```

i want to know how could u can verify hash and make sure that the password entered by user is equal to the the password saved hashed in database while using microtime ?!

and that was the code for hash verify

```
    private function verify_hash($password,$hash)
{
    return $hash == crypt($password, $hash);
}
```

and how the last code works to verify hash ?  ( the crypt method)

Comment: why would you not just use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`?

Comment: @developerwjk that was the example i saw i`m asking about if this right or wrong ? also how this code works  $hash == crypt($password, $hash);  to verify hash

Comment: This is explained (in a note above the 1st example) in the php documentation for `crypt()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of PHP 5.5, you can use `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` for hashing passwords much more conveniently than rolling with `crypt()`.

To hash the password:

```
$hash = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT );
```

Then to verify what the user has typed in against the hash:

```
if ( password_verify( $password, $hash )) {
    // Password is good
}
```

Comment: and is it possible to use microtime in salt as i mentioned and how to check password match as microtime is nothing known ?

Comment: @SamehKhaled, it's possible to specify your own salt value like this: `$hash = password_hash( $password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array( 'salt' = microtime() ));`, but it is not desired.  If you don't specify a salt, one is randomly generated for you by `password_hash()`.  Using a time as a salt is not a good idea, because it's fairly easily predictable (though `microtime()` is certainly better than `time()` in that regard).

Comment: u dont understand what i want
when hashing password it stored in database and to check if the the entered password is right we hash it and match
the two hashed password so how is it done if i was using microtime the two password cannot be hashed as same

Comment: I do understand what you want, and the answer I provided will do exactly what you want.. it's exactly how we do the same thing all the time. `password_verify()` is able to match them even if the salts don't match. Please try the code that I posted in my answer.. it will do what you're asking for, and no need to provide a salt.

Comment: @SamehKhaled `"u dont understand what i want..."` did you read the link i posted?